# Archiving fails due to undefined Symbols for Google Analytics

Tags: ios, linker, google-analytics, xcode5, cocoapods

I have integrated GAI using the most recent cocoapods version.

When I build in the Debug config everything runs just fine.
However, as soon as I try to archive the Application the compiler fails with the following messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIDictionaryBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libWLCore.a(WLTrackingHelper.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libWLCore.a(WLTrackingHelper.o)
  "_kGAIScreenName", referenced from:
      +[WLTrackingHelper trackView:] in libWLCore.a(WLTrackingHelper.o)
      +[WLTrackingHelper resetView] in libWLCore.a(WLTrackingHelper.o)
  "_kGAIAnonymizeIp", referenced from:
      +[WLTrackingHelper prepareDefaultTracker:withAnonymization:withUnCaughtExceptions:withDebug:] in libWLCore.a(WLTrackingHelper.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Since it works in Debug I tried to figure out where the difference in the configuration between Debug and Release lies.
I found out that the Other linker flags in Release are empty whereas in Debug contains the flag for GoogleAnalytics and other frameworks and libraries.

After adding the flags to the Release Configuration of Other linker flags I got

```
library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
```

After that, I added libPods and after that libPods-GoogleAnalytics to the Link Binary With Libraries section but the errors remained the same.

I invested almost 2 days into that problem, but I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some fiddling I found the solution by adding not the library generated by cocoa pods (libPods-GoogleAnalytics), but directly linking the libGoogleAnalyticsServices to my main project. Still, I think this is not the most elegant solution possible since the linker should know that the symbols he was missing were available already, as provided by cocoapods.

Comment: Hello, it works if you link the static library to the Analytics cocoapod project as well. I think this is like 5% better.

Comment: @TiborUdvari how?

Answer (score 3):

Please confirm you have added $(inherited) to Other Linker Flags (Build Settings) as in the below image. Add the same in Release also, otherwise the same error will pop up at the time of archiving.
[image]